# Copy a folder in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, permissions, copy

I am trying to copy a folder. But I am getting error `Error while copying "file.zip".`

On the other hand if I try use **copy to**, I am getting this error :

> Error while coping.   The folder "file" cannot be copied because you
>   do not have permissions to create it in the destination.

How can I copy a folder from one directory to another directory ?

Thanks

Comment: Get the permissions to do so in the destination folder. Or give more details.

Comment: Open terminal and do `ls -l /path/to/destination folder`. Then see what is the user ownership and group ownership of that folder. If you do not belong to those groups , you could add yourself to those groups, and then you will have permissions. If that directory is root owned, using `sudo cp file.zip /path/to/destination` will suffice.

Comment: @Serg to see the directory permissions, you need `ls -ld /path/to/directory`, otherwise it will list directory's content!

Comment: @ByteCommander  right, good catch !

Comment: Thanks @Serg for your reply. I would like to have facility like windows copy paste. How can I do that ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Ubuntu file manager doesn't have an option to open folders with elevated permissions; you need `nautilus-admin` plugin for that.

Open `Software Center` and search for `nautilus-admin` package. Install it. Once the plug in has been added, stop file manager (the command for that is `nautilus -q`) and restart it.

Now, you can copy and paste files in file manager with Admin permissions , if you right-click on body of the folder and select "Open as Administrator".

However, if the folder where you try to copy the file has permissions other than root user, for example `userA:userA` , *you will have to use command line* to add yourself to userA group (considering that you have `sudo` privileges). *There is no GUI way to do that!*

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, open Terminal and type: `sudo nautilus &`

That will open Nautilus as the superuser. You can copy anything anywhere you want, and it doesn't require installing anything.

Answer (score -1):

move it with terminal as admin eg

sudo mv campfund /location/